# Access denied error in boost-bjam isntallation

Tags: boost, bjam

i'm trying to lunch bjam as a step to install the boost library, needed to run Cufflinks (RNASeq analysis software).
however, when i run the code:

```
$ ./bjam --prefix=/cygdrive/c/cygdrive/c/Boost/include/boost-1_53/boost -- toolset=gcc architecture=x86 address_model=32 link=static runtime-link=static stage install
```

i get the following error

```
Access is denied.
Access is denied.
Access is denied.
Access is denied.
C:/Users/se24553/Downloads/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build\property.jam:328: in validate1 from module property
error: Invalid property '<address_model>32': unknown feature 'address_model'.
C:/Users/se24553/Downloads/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build\property.jam:337: in property.validate from module property
C:/Users/se24553/Downloads/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build\build-request.jam:216: in convert-command-line-element from module build-request
C:/Users/se24553/Downloads/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build\build-request.jam:154: in build-request.from-command-line from module build-request
C:/Users/se24553/Downloads/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:613: in load from module build-system
C:\Users\se24553\Downloads\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
C:\Users\se24553\Downloads\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
C:\Users\se24553\Downloads\boost_1_53_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

and I don't really know how to overcome that.
the directory `/cygdrive/c/cygdrive/c/Boost/` (and i tried to use only this path but the result is the same) is where i have installed the various files using the code `b2 install --prefix=/cygdrive/c/cygdrive/c/Boost/`, however, it contains two folders `include` and `lib`, `lib` is empty while `include` contains --> `boost-1_53` --> `boost` and here there are all the other folders and the `.hpp` files.

i am using cygdrive on Win 7 if that helps!

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:
In windows 7 your bin directory may be protected:

```
$ chmod -R a+r bin
$ chmod -R a+x bin
```

[How to compile Boost (and link?) libraries in cygwin windows7 i686-w64-mingw32-g++ with bjam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849828/how-to-compile-boost-and-link-libraries-in-cygwin-windows7-i686-w64-mingw32-g)

Barthelemy